# I can't login to website using httpwebrequest

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm trying login to website(example: https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1) using httpwebrequest by POST. But It's not return result after login.

I don't know what is wrong with my code, can you help me? Thanks so much!

This is my code:

```
        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Uri myUri = new System.Uri("https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1");
        HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(myUri);
        myRequest.Method = "POST";
        myRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        myRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), myRequest);

    }

    void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
    {
            HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
            // End the stream request operation
            Stream postStream = myRequest.EndGetRequestStream(callbackResult);
            StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
            postData.Append("email=myEmail");
            postData.Append("&password=myPassword");
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData.ToString());
            postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, postData.Length);
            postStream.Close();
            myRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponsetStreamCallback), myRequest);
    }
    void GetResponsetStreamCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
    {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(callbackResult);
            using (StreamReader httpWebStreamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string result = httpWebStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
                //For debug: show results
                Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                   // something do
                });
            }

    }
```

Comment: So what does it return? In which method? Are all three methods hit? Was does your debugger say?

Comment: It was return login page(so not login).I can't find error, basically the sample copied from http://transoceanic.blogspot.com/2011/09/wp7-sending-post-data-and-receive.html

Answer (score 0):

I had just a quick look: https://www.facebook.com/login.php 's input fields are named "email" and "pass" (not "password"). 
Untested: Change

```
postData.Append("&password=myPassword");
```

to

```
postData.Append("&pass=myPassword");
```

Even if this works, I doubt that you get much further with whatever you intend to do. I recommend using one of the Facebook SDKs.

Comment: This is a example for my project, I use localhost for my app: http://localhost/moodle/login/index.php And input fields are name "username" and "password", but it's still not run. I'm trying for more addrees but not successfull. Help me, please!

Comment: Your code in the first posting requests Facebook. If it's instead requesting a service on YOUR machine, then you should debug this service to find out why login fails.